# How to add an SXA rendering variant to the toolbox?

Tags: sxa, presentation

I have a custom rendering variant under site "A" (under `Presentation > Rendering Variants > Navigation`) and I want to add that to the Experience Editor's toolbox so that it's available for site "B".

However, when I go to `Presentation > Available Renderings > Navigation` and try to select the rendering, I'm not able to see it. Presumably, the rendering variant doesn't exist in `Layout`? Did I miss a step somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add Rendering Variants to the toolbox. The toolbox shows renderings. In your case you are using the `Navigation` rendering. Once you have added the `Navigation` rendering to a page, then you can select that rendering and change the rendering variant.

[image]

You can see the OOTB rendering variants for the `Navigation` rendering here: https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/the-sxa-renderings-and-rendering-variants.html#navigation_body